# How can I get the page that sent a request to my REST API?

Tags: php

I am trying to retrieve the full URL of the page that uses an API.

Like: index.php makes a call to the API for homepage content. I'd like to be able to know if that request actually came from index.php or if it originated from a different page on the site.

I had thought I could use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` but that's returning the API's URL every time. Beyond that I can require an additional parameter and just send over the current URL with the request, but I'd like to avoid doing this if it's possible.

The end goal is to see whether the request is being viewed on the actual API page for tests, or if it's really being used in the wild.

Comment: @Sammitch can you elaborate? Why would this be a bad idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` which contains the URL of the page which request came from.

More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will contain the API's URL. There's no way to determine the URL of the PHP script which made the request.

Comment: This didn't really answer the question, but it did actually end up working for me. If it fires on the actual API page `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will display any $_GET variables, but it doesn't when used somewhere else. Not entirely sure what's up with that, but either way it did the trick, thank you!

Comment: @SamBeers I wanted see through what you really want to do. If this answer satsify you, you can accept it to close question.